# About "email alerts" wording in Salesforce Help Doc

Tags: workflow, limits, email-alert

I am a bit confused about this wording on the help doc on "Daily Allocations for Email Alerts" (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_limits_email.htm&type=5):

> Each org can send single emails to a maximum of 5,000 external email
>   addresses per day based on Greenwich Mean Time (GMT). (...) For orgs
>   created in Spring ’19 and later, the daily limit is also enforced for
>   **email alerts**, simple email actions, Send Email actions in flows, and
>   REST API.

What exactly are the "email alerts" listed in the above sentence? I am only aware of the Workflow Action kind of Email Alerts, but those are supposed to count against Daily Workflow Email Allocation as noted above in the same help doc. As a matter of fact, emails sent using Workflow Alerts do get registered as Daily Workflow Emails from my testing. Could someone help clarifying this?

Edit: To make my question clearer, I am confused about the apparent contradicting statements regarding Email Alerts daily limit. At the top of the help page I linked, Email Alerts limit is stated to be `1,000 per standard Salesforce license per org...The overall org allocation is 2,000,000`. But below, in the paragraph regarding Single Emails limit (5000 per day per org), Email Alerts are mentioned to count against "the daily limit", which I assume to be the Single Emails one in this context.

Comment: Maybe this will provide better context to your limits: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312442&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: Thank you for the link Ronnie. Unfortunately I think it wasn't relevant to my question. I will try to edit my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two different limits.

1. Daily email alert limit -WFR Alert
2. External address limit - any email not sent to a contact or user record. Basically it uses and email address

They are mutually exclusive but can affect each other

Comment: External address limit is in other words Single emails limit right? Our production org (Partner Enterprise) once exceeded our daily Single emails limit but not Workflow emails limit, so while we wasn't able to send anymore single email for the day, workflow alerts were still working as usual.

Comment: No. External address is a subset of single email. If you set the targeted of an email to a user or contact it counts for single but not for external. If you don’t and instead send to an email address it counts for both